# Have instant move operations between subst drive and host drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, subst

I have a subst partition. Let say `D:\X\ -> X:`

I need 3 features along with it.

A) Recycle Bin (Found tricks already for that)

B) Instant move operations between `D:` and `X:`

C) No access to `D:\X\` by any program. If I open `X:\exe.exe`, for some reason, some programs like Windows Firewall, see it as `D:\X\exe.exe`.

How do I achieve goal B and C. I am open to completing use different feature rather than `subst` if they can solve my problems.

Comment: Your requirement C doesn't make any sense as it would be accessible through its regular path.

Comment: Also B is only possible through the regular path.